# Can HTML5 communicate with peripherals like scanners and credit card readers?

Tags: html, peripherals

My company writes software that installs on client machines to perform point-of-sale transactions.  The software interfaces with a variety of external peripherals (receipt printers, bar code scanners, credit-card readers, etc). We do this with a WinForms app that we created in Visual Studio using the Microsoft OPOS library, which in turn communicates with our cloud server.

There are obvious inefficiencies in this model, primarily with updates.  I'm researching other ways to communicate with these peripherals over the web, preferably via web browser. So far as I can tell, Java is one of the only technologies out there that can do what we're looking for (via applet), and I assume Adobe Flash can as well (via the Air platform).  These are viable, but not preferable because we want to run our software on web-enabled mobile devices.

Does anybody have suggestions for other ways to communicate with external peripherals over the web?

Comment: What are your requirements for support for it? E.g. Can it only work on the latest version of one browser, or is it needed to be compatible to old versions of IE?

Comment: We get to dictate what browser the client uses.  Chrome would be ideal, because there are working Chromium builds for every major platform (windows, linux, iOS, etc).

Comment: Some organizations don't allow Adobe software on their systems. I know two US federal agencies and several private companies that have the policy. Adobe has the dubious distinction of writing the most insecure software in the world.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**UPDATE (Jan 16th, 2019):** The [Credential Management API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Credential_Management_API#Browser_compatibility) has been announced. It's [currently only supported on Chrome and Opera](https://caniuse.com/#feat=credential-management) but it's looking promising. Google Developers wrote [an article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/credential-management/) elaborating on the spec.

**UPDATE (Dec 28th, 2016):** Another couple years gone, and another update. This one will be more focused on two new developments than anything else. See the new "WebUSB & Web BlueTooth" section under "Full Device API". But the answer remains the same.

**UPDATE (Nov 3rd, 2014):** It's been just over two years since the original post was made, but the answer remains mostly the same for now. We are, however, closer to your original goal in several areas.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

There would be a number of ways to go about this.

### Background

The HTML5 specification has entered into the "Recommendation" state. This means that HTML5 is pretty much set for what it looks like. However, I will be using HTML5 in the same way that every marketing person in the world has decided is best. That is, I will not be talking about HTML. Well, I will, in so far as you will utilize it from an HTML page, but not really. What I'll actually be discussing is JavaScript (JS) and [that's a horse of a different color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#History). But for all intents and purposes, we're putting it all under the same heading as HTML5, which has been decided to mean "shiny and new" now.

Also, the items which I am discussing will vary in support. Some are very browser dependent projects (like Chromium specific implementations), and some are more standards driven projects that may not have browsers implementing or experimenting with them yet. I'll try to distinguish between the two as I go along.

### Full Device API

**Status: Incoming, but not ready**

Being able to access devices from the browser is making slow but steady progress. Right now, many modern browsers have access to some of the more common devices like [the camera](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC) or [gamepads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad), but they are all high level APIs. [Browser vendors](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI), [the standards groups](http://www.w3.org/2009/dap/), and lots of companies involved with the web are all trying to make webapps just as powerful as your local applications.

But the APIs you are looking for are still in progress and a ways off. For your particular case, and for the more general case of connecting your webapp to most devices, we're still a few years away from something we can use. If you want to see what awesome things are coming up in that field, here are just a select few items that may help you directly:

- [Web Near Field Communication (NFC) API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-nfc-20140114/)
  This one unfortunately may be dead in the water for now. But it looks like originally some folks at the W3C (mostly Intel it looks like) were looking at adding a NFC API to the web.
- [Media Capture Streams](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-mediacapture-streams-20120628/)
  The WebRTC group is working on programmatic access to media streams like the camera which would allow to integrate things like barcode scanning or other features. This has reached CR status and is [available in browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream), but is less helpful on its own.
- [Web Bluetooth](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/)
  If you had bluetooth capable tools, this API would help you connect with them from computers and devices that were able to listen and connect. The primary driver for this at the moment seems like it is the Chrome team, including an experimental implementation, but I wouldn't consider it anywhere ready to use yet (See "WebUSB & Web BlueTooth" section).
- [WebUSB](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/)
  This would allow full access to low level USB information including listing devices and interacting with them. Same as Web BlueTooth, this seems to be current Chrome pet project, but I also wouldn't rely on it (See "WebUSB & Web BlueTooth" section).
- [Network Service Discovery](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-discovery-api-20140220/)
  If you have other devices or items on the network which broadcast and use HTTP, this API would allow you to discover and interact with these services. No browser implementation, but it is in a working draft for the W3C.

Originally, Mozilla was pushing a number of these forward because of Boot2Gecko (or Firefox OS). However, with that project officially cancelled, we aren't seeing much progress from them in these areas now.

Members of the Chrome team, however, seem to have decided to dive in and start not only working towards these, but putting them live in browsers. Which leads us to...

#### WebUSB & Web BlueTooth

> Like sausages, it's better to not know how Web Standards are made
> -Abraham Lincoln (probably)

There's been a little bit of buzz in this area as it looks like the Chrome team snuck in these as experimental features and developed their own specification for it. Which is great! Just maybe not in the way that you were hoping for.

Each browser vendor and W3C contributor group has their own style and makes contributions towards the specs in their own way. The result is *usually* a fairly decent specification that the browsers have agreed upon. But getting from nothing to something is... messy. Real messy. And is quite a process a lot of times. It doesn't always result in a good spec (yeah, I'm talking about you Florian compromise...) but even when it does, it takes a while.

However, It seems like Google developed this version of the spec all on their own. And, in my experience, Google's approach to the specs is always a little... well... setting my personal opinions aside we'll say "gung-ho". They tend to just dive right into the deep end. And that seems to be what they've done here.

**I highly doubt these specs or implementations will look anything like this when they become standards**. And there's nothing wrong with that. That's part of the process. But I wouldn't go relying on this implementation or developing any code or products against it. This is an unprecedented feature on the web and all the browser vendors are gonna want a big say in this.

That said, this is actually good. One of the things Google often does (for better or worse) with situations like this is forces the conversation and it can push things along. And having a feature shipped in the browser, even an experimental feature, can turn up the heat on the demand for it. So we may see more progress in this area soon.

### <del>PhoneGap</del> Apache Cordova. You know, for your phone

**Status: Not fully featured and phone only**

[Apache Cordova](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/), previously [Adobe PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), is a way to write your program in HTML, CSS, and JS that allows you to access lower level functionality on things like phones, and compile across devices. This would be a way to implement your program, but it would be a phone application, not necessarily a desktop one. An option to consider, and something I figured I would mention.

Cordova implements a few of the above features already, but doesn't have some of the more powerful ones like NFC or BlueTooth.

### The Native-App solution (for Windows 8)

**Status: Possible, but OS specific and desktop app**

Windows 8 offers the ability to build applications in HTML and JS. This would allow you to easily access lower level functionality on the OS via [their API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377). From the looks of it, it is pretty extensive and you can do a lot. You mentioned cross OS support, however, and this obviously limits you to one OS.

### It's so Flash-y!

**Status: Dying/Dead, not possible as a web app**

Flash won't have direct access to the system through the web. You could create an AIR application, but that will sort of defeat the purpose of having it web based. In addition, Flash support on mobile, and on the web it would seem, is on the decline.

### NodeJS

**Status: Can be a bit of a pain and only possible as a desktop app**

NodeJS and JS applications have sort of been a hot topic the last couple years. I didn't discuss it in my original post because I felt it wasn't quite there yet. However, things have progressed and it is much closer to being ready for this sort of thing, and has the support and power of a growing user base. That said, for your particular case, I wouldn't recommend using it. It would have to be local on the users machine, and because of how NodeJS (and similar engines) are at the moment, it would require a lot of extra configuration and setup that would complicate things a bit.

So you could build an app using HTML, CSS and JS with NodeJS or similar engines and have low level access to what you need, but it has to be local, and it would take more work than I'm sure you want to do every time you'd like to install it for a customer.

### ... Now where was I?

So where does that leave us? Well, simple: if you want a single language/set of code as your code base, HTML/CSS/JS aren't a great option... yet. But they could be some day. For now, your options are limited to what you feel is best for your customer. Java is a stable option you listed, but obviously comes with its own drawbacks. As the web develops, I think we'll see a lot of really cool things coming out of the new functionality, but we've got a ways to go still.

#### More reading:

- [Brian.IO: Beyond HTML5](http://brian.io/slides/beyond-html5/)
- [HTML5 Apps on Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx)
- [Wikipedia list of projects built using JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Uses_outside_web_pages)

Comment: Note: [Adobe is switching to maintenance releases only on mobile Flash](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/perlow/exclusive-adobe-ceases-development-on-mobile-browser-flash-refocuses-efforts-on-html5-updated/19226).

Comment: It seems that [Electron](http://electron.atom.io) is looking good for this. I haven't gone into this in detail, but it seems to be a cross-platform HTML5 application building tool supporting all the node.js capabilities. This may able to create a single executable for multiple platforms, solving all the "packaging" difficulties.

Answer (score 12):

This is possible, but it would have to be done indirectly. In theory, you could write a socket-server in a low level language, which gets I/O, and sends the I/O through the socket (relaying, I guess). HTML5 uses WebSockets, or some equivalent to communicate with this socket-server.

Comment: Hmm..so how do I go about facilitating communication between the web browser and the credit card reader?

Comment: You wouldn't. You would communicate with a server, written in say, C++, which communicates with the web browser. C++ is however able to talk to the credit card reader.

Comment: This is how we are doing browser-based TWAIN scanning. You have to install a local application or service, written in a language that _can_ communicate with the device you need to talk to. The application then (for example) runs an HTTP, HTTPS, WS or WSS server on a port on localhost, and your local js can talk to that.

Comment: @Spike0xff Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 5):

Now it can be achieved with [WebUSB](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/) API.

It is [available in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web) since version 54.

It is a W3C editor's draft so we can expect (hope) that it will be adopted by other browser vendors...

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this a lot lately... have a POS app mostly written in VB6, considering what to do next.  HTML5 is an option and I was thinking I'd use VSPE to get the serial stuff into the JS.

http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html

Love this product!  Works very well for getting serial traffic where you need it, so I think it would work well, at least as a proof-of-concept to get you going.  You'll want to use a combination of "connector" types along with the "tcpclient" and "tcpserver".

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, a method that works well in 2016 (since chrome 26), but is to be [withdrawn over the next 2 years](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html) is to deploy your html5 as a chrome app and use [chrome.usb](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb) (or chrome.serial or chrome.bluetooth).

I am currently using chrome.usb and planning to migrate to a web app using [WebUSB API](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/) (see Supersharp's answer), which I hope will be adopted by the time Google discontinue chrome apps .