# Interacting with peripheral devices via website

Tags: javascript, html

How can I open a peripheral device such as a cash register through a website.  For example a web based POS system that needs to be able to open and close a cash register.

Comment: This is probably off topic but look into rasberry PI

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021723/can-html5-communicate-with-peripherals-like-scanners-and-credit-card-readers

Comment: This needs to be a website that acts as a POS, what did you have in mind with the rasberry pi?