# DigitalPersona Fingerprint Reader with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, applet, activex, fingerprint, biometrics

We are using DigitalPersona U.are.U SDK with JavaApplet in our ASP.Net MVC Web Application.

We are looking for alternative solutions to implement the same. I have searched and found the following ways but none of them meet our requirements.

```
 1. ActiveX (Limited to IE 10 and earlier versions, no support for Firefox).
 2. BHO - Browser Helper Objects (also deprecated and not supported in Modern Browsers)
 3. Desktop app installed on end user's machine which communicates with the web app and confirms when user has verified fingerprints. (Not a workable solution).
```

I have heard some people saying that HTML5 Canvas is being used for Bio-metric Devices etc. Any help with finding a working alternative solution will be highly appreciated.

In case you need more information, please post a question below. Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for alternative ways to implement biometric fingerprint authentication or you are looking simply for alternative ways to implement biometric fingerprint authentication on web?

Comment: I am looking for alternative implementation for web (other than applet and other mentioned above), using the same device and same SDK.

Comment: You could give websockets a try. I have very little knowledge in that area but it is one of those viable options in the domain of web applications that looks promising.

Comment: May be in future, but not yet possible. I suggest to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13022202/3710908