# How to open an EXE file from a Client Machine through a Web Application using Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, google-chrome, client-side-scripting

How to open an EXE file from a Client Machine through a Web Application using Chrome?

I am able to open the EXE through Internet Explorer since I am using ActiveX Objects to open the Exe file through client side scripting. But since chrome does not support ActiveX I am unable to open the EXE from chrome. Can somebody provide an alternate way to open the exe from chrome?

I know it works if IETab addon is added to the browser for supporting ActiveX. But the client policy will not accept adding add-ons.

I am trying for a solution as such in WebEx websites where a temporary application is run once and each time it is accessed it opens in the temporary app without each time installing it.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start an external application from a Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652094/start-an-external-application-from-a-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: Not exactly. I am not talking about chrome extensions. I hope it is not clear. In fact I have a page in my web application for performing document scan. From that page I need to open the scanner application exe installed locally on a button click. This works fine in Internet Explorer with the help of ActiveX Object in Javascript.  I need to perform the same in chrome also. But ActiveX cannot be used in chrome. Hence I am searching for alternatives.

Comment: Does https://www.dynamsoft.com/blog/document-imaging/scanner-chrome-firefox-safari/ help?

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple answer, **NO!** it's not possible just by using plain HTML5/JavaScript API, and thank god it's not possible or else the consequences would be devastating! Imagine any random website executing a file on your computer! That would be the worst security nightmare!

*But, there are workarounds!*
1. You can, for example, use Flash (but [you shouldn't](https://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2017/07/adobe-flash-update.html)) or Silverlight but as mentioned the OP doesn't want any plugin-based solution so I guess they are not as useful.
2. Another solution would be to deploy a Desktop agent, if possible, and then communicate with it using a local Rest API and handle all the native access in that Desktop agent.

Still, the *most preferred* way would be to just ask your user to scan (or whatever) the document and upload it to your site.

More references can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13022202/6611700)

Comment: You can open an .exe from a web application by [registering a custom URL protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows).